# PowerShell runs a powershell function with a different domain account

Tags: sql, powershell, networkcredentials

I have a quite large PowerShell script with several parts/modules/functions to automatize maintenance steps. Let’s call it as a “library”. I need to develop an additional layer (a kind of “engine”) which calls the functions in a given order with the appropriate parameters. To do so, I have a config file (xml) describing the steps and several user accounts (names, passwords). One account is for copying files, another one is for working with sql servers, and so on.

For example, one of the steps is to perform an sql backup operation by a given user account, which is a domain service user. I have a backup function in the “library” which contains a Backup-SqlDatabase or Invoke-SQLCmd to do the work. I don’t know which one. I can add the user name and password to this function as a parameter, but they can work with only sql account data, not a windows/domain account. But my configuration file may contain for this step a domain service user account.

I would love a method to switch session, to become a given domain user for the execution of a PowerShell function. I do not know if the Invoke-Command is the best for me, as I do not want to execute a script in a remote computer, and the PowerShell function is inside my library.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Checkig Push-ImpersonationContext at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SecurityFever/2.2.0 ...

Comment: Interesting, it seems working, the user is switched when I ask what is the current user name it shows the new user name. But when I execute operations (call robocopy or something) - it still runs with the original user rights. :( sad.